# Using Bash Scripting To Export Results of Linux Commands Top And History To Text File

Tags: linux, bash

I've been asked to demo exporting a list of linux command results into a single text file. The commands top and history seem problematical

I have tried

```
top >> christopherCollins.txt
history >> christopherCollins.txt
```

Possible solutions which I have below are

```
top -b -n 5 >> christopherCollins.txt
grep -v "^#" $HISTFILE >> christopherCollins.txt
```

Although top -b -n 5 >> christopherCollins.txt , seems to work for getting some results from top command, I wonder if there is anything better?

When I try to export history
grep -v "^#" $HISTFILE > christopherCollins.txt works on the terminal with one > , but when I use two >> as an append method in my bashscript it seems to bring the process to a halt when I run the script.
I have also considered if I can change the order I append results to file, things just don't seem to append well when I use grep -v "^#" $HISTFILE, I can only at moment create one file containing history results.

I use the following commands to execute my script.

```
chmod +x mybashcommands.sh
bash mybashcommands.sh
```

My full bash script code below is as follows, with some edits to show breaks between the command results

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "date" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
date >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "hostname" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
hostname >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "arch" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
arch >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "uname -a" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
uname -a >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "uptime" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
uptime >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "whoami" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
whoami >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "who" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
who >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "finger" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
finger >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "w" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
w >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "top -b -n 5" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
top -b -n 5 >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "history" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
grep -v "^#" $HISTFILE >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "" >> christopherCollins.txt
echo "END------------------------------------------------------------" >> christopherCollins.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Redirect your whole commands group at once:

Also note that the `$HISTFILE` environment variable is only valid in interactive session and is empty/undefined within a script scope.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

{
  printf '\ndate\n\n'
  date
  printf '\nhostname\n\n'
  hostname
  printf '\narch\n\n'
  arch
  printf '\nuname -a\n\n'
  uname -a
  printf '\nuptime\n\n'
  uptime
  printf '\nwhoami\n\n'
  whoami
  printf '\nwho\n\n'
  who
  printf '\nfinger\n\n'
  finger
  printf '\nw\n\n'
  w
  printf '\ntop -b -n5\n\n'
  top -b -n5
  printf '\nhistory\n\n'
  grep -v "^#" "$HOME/.bash_history"
} >christopherCollins.txt
```

Or more programmatically to shorten code:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

history() {
  grep -v "^#" "$HOME/.bash_history"
}

for command in 'date' 'hostname' 'arch' 'uname -a' 'uptime' 'whoami' 'who' 'finger' 'w' 'top -b -n5' 'history'; do
  printf '\n%s\n\n' "$command"
  set -- $command
  "$@"
done >christopherCollins.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Léa Gris your solutions are perfect. Much appreciated.